# Code first не создается миграция

Tags: c#, mvc, codefirst

[Rep](https://bitbucket.org/NikitaJe/learning/src/Develop/MVCStore/MVSStore/)

Migration

```
namespace MVSStore.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class New : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

соединена:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVSStore.Models.Data
{
    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PagesDTO> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model DB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVSStore.Models.Data
{
    [Table("MVCStore")]
    public class PagesDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int Sorting { get; set; }
        public bool HasSidebar { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Почему миграция пустая? Почему не создаются поля?

Первый раз вроде все нормально создалось, потом Я что то затупил удалил папку миграции. И давай новые создавать и они пустые

```
PM> get-migrations
Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
202104231114090_thr
202104231102309_sec
202104231041067_first
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123422/discussion-on-question-by---code-first---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все решается куда проще чем кажется.

```
 <add name="Db" connectionString="Data Source=trnh-app-01;Initial Catalog=MVSStore1;User ID=sa;Password=159654;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

name="ХХ" должно советовать классу подключения

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebApplication1.Models.Data
{
    public class ***Db*** : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PageDTO> Pages { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

На счет миграций в ручную из проекта удалил, базу данных тоже.
Поменял строку подключения все заработало как и должно